# NSIS and HKLM, Use of string

Tags: installation, windows-installer, nsis

I used a wizard to create an NSIS installer, and then reviewed the code:
It defined a variable called PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY as "HKLM":

```
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY "HKLM"
```

And then used it like this:

```
WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayName" "$(^Name)"
```

I was wondering if ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} is: HKLM, or "HKLM", and if it still references that directory if the folder is named differently (Mine is called "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE").

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run the code to see what was this line writing to the registry?

Comment: @CharlesB What do you mean? I really try not to mess with this, since I know nothing about the registry, and a tutorial on the NSIS page said that if it writes something wrong to the registry, It can erase a lot of things..

Comment: So when will you know your code works if you don't test it? Use a virtual machine if you don't want to mess with your system. And registry is not that complicated, it's just a tree where you write (key,value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HKLM **is** HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (It is a pretty common alias) and HKCU is HKEY_CURRENT_USER etc.

`!define PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY "HKLM"` is the same as `!define PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY HKLM`
but you really only need quotes if the string contains a space.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I couldn't find this anywhere

Comment: What is `HKCR` as in `WriteRegStr HKCR ".pep" "" "pep.Document"` which appears to be used to create file extension association? `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`?

Comment: @richard Correct